# Can we use Identity Server 4 as an API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am new to Identity Server. I have a doubt. Can we use Identity Server as API? My idea is to give Identity Server the responsibility of Authentication too. So that I can pass the username and password entered by user from my Presentation layer to Identity Server. If the credentials are valid, Identity Server will return the user's details back to my MVC Controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can, but this isn't a good question for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to enable ResourceOwnerGrant on your IdentityServer project.